# Descartar los objetos con valores repetidos en un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cómo puedo descartar los objetos con valores repetidos en un array de objetos?

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más específico?

Comment: En un array de objetos ejemplo: 

var data=[
  { id:3, name:"Bet" },
  { id:1, name:"Ana" },
  { id:2, name:"Dan" },
  { id:3, name:"Bet" },
  { id:2, name:"Dan" },
  { id:2, name:"Ext" },
  { id:4, name:"Pem" }
] 

Descartar los valores repetidos ejemplo:

{ id:2, name:"Dan" },
{ id:2, name:"Dan" }

Comment: Pero ya me respondieron justo lo que necesitaba. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podria no ser necesario usar `filter()` pero de todas maneras, se puede.
Usando un array para almacenar los valores distintos, se pueden ir descartando los repetidos. En este caso, el objeto completo se serializa.

```js
var data=[
  { id:3, name:"Bet" },
  { id:1, name:"Ana" },
  { id:2, name:"Dan" },
  { id:3, name:"Bet" },
  { id:2, name:"Dan" },
  { id:2, name:"Ext" },
  { id:4, name:"Pem" }
]

var repetidos=[];

var unicos=data.filter(function(item){
   var content=JSON.stringify(item);
   if (repetidos.indexOf(content)>=0){
        return false;
   }
   repetidos.push(JSON.stringify(item));
   return true;
});

console.log(unicos);
```

En el caso de filtrar repetidos por una sola propiedad, basta cambiar `content` a una propiedad en particular (o una combinacion de ellas):

```
var content=JSON.stringify(item['propiedad']);
```

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que necesitaba. Gracias.