# Eliminar objetos repetidos de un array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un array object y quiero eliminar los repetidos.

Por ejemplo del siguiente se repite IdCatalogo=37 dos veces entonces quiero que se borren ambos objetos

```html
[
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 34},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 35},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 36},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 37},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 37},
]
```

Y me quede asi:

```html
[
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 34},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 35},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 36}
]
```

He intentado lo siguiente pero sigue manteniendo uno de los duplicados

```html
   const [myarray, setmyarray] = useState([]);
   
   let set = new Set(myarray.map(JSON.stringify))
   let arrSinDuplicaciones = Array.from(set).map(JSON.parse);

    console.log(arrSinDuplicaciones);
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Te sugiero leer el apartado "Como preguntar?", la idea del sitio es ayudar a resolver problemas, no hacer el trabajo por quien pregunta. Debes dar ejemplos de lo que has intentado, que resultado esperas obtener y en que estás trancado.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el origen de esos datos y por qué los obtienes repetidos? Considera filtrar en el origen, así evitas transportar datos para luego desechar parte de ellos, lo cual es una pésima práctica.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/381312/80870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal cual dicen en los comentarios, lo ideal sería filtrarlos antes enviarlos.

Pero si aún así deseas hacerlo quizás lo siguiente te sirva.

Esta función debe recibir como parametro el array que desees, y esta te retornará un nuevo array sin esos elementos.

```
function borrarRepetidos(array) {
  const copiaArray = [...array]; // Para no trabajar sobre el original, no es recomendable
  const valoresRepetidos = []; // Aquí guardarémos los valores que se repitan, solo se guarda una vez cada uno.

  const arrayOrdenado = copiaArray.sort(
    (a, b) => a.IdCatalogo - b.IdCatalogo,
    0
  ); //Ordeno el array por IdCatalogo (Por las dudas que no siempre esté ordenado)

  // Recorro todos los elementos de array ordenado iniciando en 1
  for (let i = 1; i < arrayOrdenado.length; i++) {
      //Verifico si la posición i-1 = i
    if (arrayOrdenado[i - 1].IdCatalogo === arrayOrdenado[i].IdCatalogo) {
        //Me fijo si el valor de IdCatalogo no está ya en valoresRepetidos
      if (!valoresRepetidos.includes(arrayOrdenado[i].IdCatalogo)) {
         //Si arriba dio que no estaba lo agrego al array
        valoresRepetidos.push(arrayOrdenado[i].IdCatalogo);
      }
    }
  }

  //Retorno arrayOrdenado filtrado, devolviendo solo los objetos cuyo IdCatalogo es diferente a los incluidos en valoresRepetidos
  return arrayOrdenado.filter(
    (item) => !valoresRepetidos.includes(item.IdCatalogo)
  );
}
```

---

Si lo que deseas es borrarlos del arrray original, podrías hacer algo así, el array estaría por fuera de la función o dentro, dependiendo de el scope deseado, solo debe llamarse "array".

```
function borrarRepetidos() {
  const valoresRepetidos = []; // Aquí guardarémos los valores que se repitan, solo se guarda una vez cada uno.

  const arrayOrdenado = array.sort((a, b) => a.IdCatalogo - b.IdCatalogo, 0); //Ordeno el array por IdCatalogo (Por las dudas que no siempre esté ordenado)

  // Recorro todos los elementos de array ordenado iniciando en 1
  for (let i = 1; i < arrayOrdenado.length; i++) {
    //Verifico si la posición i-1 = i
    if (
      arrayOrdenado[i - 1].IdCatalogo === arrayOrdenado[i].IdCatalogo && //Si hay 2 numeros consecutivos iguales
      arrayOrdenado[i].IdCatalogo !== // Y el último de ellos no es igual al último subido al valoresRepetidos
        valoresRepetidos[valoresRepetidos.length - 1]
    ) {
      //Entonces agrego a valoresRpetidos
      valoresRepetidos.push(arrayOrdenado[i].IdCatalogo);
    }
  }
  //Recorro el array original y borro el objeto cuyo IdCatalogo esté presente en valoresRepetidos
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (valoresRepetidos.includes(array[i].IdCatalogo)) {
      delete array[i];
    }
  }
  //Retorno array sin los elementos repetidos.
  return array;
}
```

Son un par de líneas más de código de lo que te pasaron en el link, pero elimina todos los repetidos, es decir no deja uno solo si se repite, también funciona para cantidad X de números repetidos y funciona si están desordenados los IdCatalogo.

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de que en stackoverflow andan muchas opciones para eliminar duplicados como las que se aprecian en esta [publicación en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array) y se pueden conseguir resultados similares para eliminar objetos por una propiedad especifica gracias a las [funciones de array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) nativas de javascript o [instancias de set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), no hay una función que se centre particularmente en el objeto como valor único.

He creado esta función que básicamente hace del objeto un `String` y luego se asegura que no exista otro similar. Esto es útil si se quiere asegurar que el conjunto del objeto tiene un valor único y no descartar objetos que pudieran tener una propiedad diferente.

Bajo esta lógica la función es Case Sensitive, pero se le pueden aplicar modificaciones para ajustarla según las reglas de negocio deseadas, en caso que la key o el valor si lo requirieran.

```js
var elements = [
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 34},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 35},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 36},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 37},
 {IdAuditoria: '32', IdCatalogo: 37},
]


function removeDuplicates(elements){
  let cleaned = []
  elements.forEach(element => {
    let encoded_value = JSON.stringify(element)
    if(cleaned.includes(encoded_value)){
      let position = cleaned.indexOf(encoded_value)
      cleaned.splice(position, 1)
    }else{
      cleaned.push(encoded_value)
    }
  })
  return cleaned.map(element => {
    return JSON.parse(element)
  })
}

console.log(removeDuplicates(elements, true))
```